# Trying to understanding why this function using foldr in Haskell isnt working

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

So I'm new to Haskell and learning it using WikiBooks. And in the higher order functions chapter, there is the following example used.

```
echoes = foldr (\ x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
```

So I tried running it, but it gives me an error as follows :

```
 * Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `foldr'
  prevents the constraint `(Foldable t0)' from being solved.
  Relevant bindings include
    echoes :: t0 Int -> [Int] (bound at HavingFun.hs:107:1)
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Foldable (Either a) -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    instance Foldable Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    ...plus one other
    ...plus 29 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the expression: foldr (\ x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
  In an equation for `echoes':
      echoes = foldr (\ x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
```

And then if I write it as follows, it works.

```
echoes lis = foldr (\ x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) [] lis
```

I am confused about this and I think this is somehow related point free definitions of functions ?
Please clarify what the problem is there here.
The link from where I'm learning - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_III

Comment: Looks like GHC needs a name to check the `Foldable` constraint.  Note that simply using the function does also work ([Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZvjW5TafmY3J3qPT)).

Comment: Ok now I'm really confused. I defined this - `echoes = foldr (\ x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []` in GHCi and it works fine but when same thing is written in a file and I reload the file, it throws that error. Moreover, what you've written in your file seems to be the same as what I've written. I don't see why mine gives an error.

Comment: That's because I used the function.  If I leave it unused I also get an error because GHC can't bind the constraint to a name ([Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yVa0Eh6NvZoJzaPP)).

Comment: see https://repl.it/repls/UnusualShockedDatalog. play with it. yes, it has to do with the partial argument list, and MonomorphismRestriction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### tl;dr

just **always write explicit type signatures**, then you're safe(r) from weird problems like that.

---

The reason this *used to work but now doesn't* is that `foldr` formerly had the signature

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

which is what the WikiBooks assumes, but in newer GHC it actually has the strictly more general signature

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

The old version *is* a special case of this, by simply choosing `t ~ []`. The reason they changed it is that you can also fold over other containers, such as arrays or maps. In fact, in your code

```
echoes = foldr (\ x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
```

there's nothing the requires the input container to be a list, either, so it would in fact work perfectly well with the signature

```
echoes :: Foldable t => t Int -> [Int]
```

...of which, again, `[Int] -> [Int]` is a special case, so that function could then be used as

```
> echoes [1,2,3]
[1,2,2,3,3,3]
```

but also as

```
> echoes $ Data.Map.fromList [('a',2), ('c',5), ('b',1)]
[2,2,1,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Or you could have given the function the list-specific signature

```
echoes' :: [Int] -> [Int]
echoes' = foldr (\x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
```

That works just the same on `[1,2,3]` but can't accept a `Map`.

The question is now, why does GHC not infer either of those signatures by itself? Well, if it had to choose one, it should be the more general `Foldable` version, because people might need to use this with other containers and wouldn't want to keep repeating the `Foldable t =>` quantifier. However, this contradicts another Haskell rule, the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). Because your `echoes` implementation doesn't *explicitly* accept any parameters (it only does that point-freely), it is a [constant applicative form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form), and a standalone CAF is supposed to have monomorphic type unless explicitly specified to be polymorphic. Thus the error message you ran into: GHC really wants this to be monomorphic, but it has no information that restricts *what* concrete `Foldable` container to pick.

There are four ways around this:

- As you noticed, by bringing the argument explicitly in scope, `echoes` is not a CAF anymore and therefore GHC infers the polymorphic type:

  ```
  echoes'' l = foldr (\x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) [] l
  ```

  ```
  > :t echoes''
  echoes'' :: Foldable t => t Int -> [Int]
  ```
- By disabling the monomorphism restriction, GHC won't care anymore whether it's CAF and just give it the more general type regardless:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
  echoes''' = foldr (\x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
  ```

  ```
  > :t echoes'''
  echoes''' :: Foldable t => t Int -> [Int]
  ```
- ***Discouraged*** If you turn on the `-XExtendedDefaultingRules` extension, GHC will automatically choose `[]` as the concrete monomorphic container for the CAF:

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
  echoes'''' = foldr (\x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
  ```

  ```
  > :t echoes''''
  echoes'''' :: [Int] -> [Int]
  ```

  GHCi has `-XExtendedDefaultingRules` enabled by default, so that's what also happens if you just declare the function in the GHCi prompt.
- ***Strongly recommended*** If you explicitly specify the signature, you and GHC both know exactly what's intended and behave accordingly, without requiring any special GHC extensions.

  ```
  echoes :: Foldable t => t Int -> [Int]
  echoes = foldr (\x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []

  echoes' :: [Int] -> [Int]
  echoes' = foldr (\x xs -> (replicate x x) ++ xs) []
  ```

  ```
  > :t echoes
  echoes :: Foldable t => t Int -> [Int]
  > :t echoes'
  echoes' :: [Int] -> [Int]
  ```

Comment: thanks for answering. (so, when `echoes` is defined  but never used, GHC doesn't know which Foldable instance to pick. When there's single use, it determines the choice and the program runs. When there are more than one uses (at different types), the monomorphism restriction still demands only one is chosen, but two are needed, so failure again.)

Comment: Just as a note: GHC only wants bounded type variables to be monomorphized in CAFs. Unbounded type variables can remain polymorphic.

Comment: @Carl what is "bounded type variables", please? googling didn't help.

Comment: "Bounded polymorphism" would get you Google hits. But in short, type variables with class constraints on them.

Comment: Good catch. I have added the (specialised) signature to `echoes` in the Wikibook.